# How to set the relative path from 'current child' without explicitly specifying/hardcoding it?

Tags: html, path

This should be relatively easy but for some reason I'm at my wit's end. Probably need a break :)

Current Page: `/Home/Desk/Drawer`

How best to specify link to Item "inside Drawer" without having a reference to Drawer? i.e. Clicking an item takes you to: `/Home/Desk/Drawer/Item`. Currently I've seen our web app store a local variable with the name `Drawer` (since it's not a fixed name but structurally positioned element in `/a/b/c/d` Hierarchy. It may not even be named as `Drawer` for some representations.

Many a times I default to using `document.URL` or having the server generate a hidden field with that name. Sounds and feels kludge-y. Any relativistic way to access the **child of the current parent/node/location**?

Ex.: `<a href = "what to put here to link to Item"> == /Home/Desk/Drawer/Item`

**UPDATE:** This is a JS intensive front-end with a Java Backend running on Glassfish/Tomcat. I'm not sure if that's important. If it's a server side way of generating then that's what we do now anyways. I'm more interested in know if this is doable simply using HTML :) (My initial guess is no; but it's still a *guess*)

Comment: have you heard about bitlyhttp://bitly.com/  and how they earn....you'll get your answer...

Comment: I've *heard* about them, but I'd surely like to *read* an answer for now :)

Comment: Can you pls let me know your Web server and server script(if any)????

Comment: @Anonymous - I'm not sure how that is useful, but added the update

Comment: I don't know I'm following you, but do you mean something like `<a href="http://x.com/user/?path=/home/desk/drawer"`? You could sessionize the last accessed I suppose, and default on session creation if necessary to a specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is known as URL mapping, which is done by specifying maps in the configuration file of the webserver.

In JSP/JSF this is done by [navigation rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFConfigure7.html)

For GlassFish following links are useful:-
[URL mapping with glassfish and spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651688/url-mapping-with-glassfish-and-spring)

For Tomcat:-
http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_web_config.htm

[This link is Javascript HTML based but smart navigators can catch it.](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/target_url_hiding.php)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What has this got to do with URL mapping? I'm asking for relativistic paths and not the mappings between them. I just want to link to that particular page with the exact same URL, no mapping in a relativistic form

Comment: As far as I understand perhaps you want link to drawer without mentioning drawer. If my understanding is right, then obvious solution is url hiding. These all links are for URL hiding(I am not so experienced with java so perhaps some fault can be there).Please correct,If I am wrong.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode it when generating the server side page and was wondering if there was an alternative. I don't want to "hide" it just want to know if it's doable without explicitly writing it.

Comment: I'll need to call my hacker friends :)... However I dont think it is possible without map or explicit coding.Because if there were one, you could have easily bypassed so many security restriction.If you dont want to hardcode you can encrypt it in javascript and set onclickevent on <a>. thats what I know :(  .....

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem exactly but why not simply use a relative link like `<a href="./Item">...</a>`?

EDIT:
Create the folder structure home/desk/drawer/item and put this in drawer/index.html:

```
<html>
<head><title>Drawer</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Drawer</h1>
<a href="./item">item/index.html</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And this in item/index.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Item</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Item</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Open the drawer/index.html with your browser and click on the link -- voila, you have reached item/index.html.

Comment: I deleted that from the post - but since you brought it up - It will link to `/Home/Desk/Item` and NOT `/Home/Desk/Drawer/Item` if you "are in Drawer"

Comment: @Phd Please see my edit -- it works, just try it out (not even a web server is required, you can simply do it from the file system)

Comment: There is NO 'index.html' anywhere. It's a page being rendered at a RESTful endpoint. There are filenames in the URL per se. Please read the very first line of my question explicitly stating "where I am i.e. current page"

Comment: Sorry, but RESTful is nowhere mentioned in your question and I also cannot see "where I am..." anywhere in your question. But as I wrote, I guess I didn't understand the question right...